# What is scheme 'c' in urlparse in Python?

Tags: python, urlparse

I think this is a bug since the documentation [does not mention anything about a scheme 'c'](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Why does the output of the following code out 'c' ? What is scheme 'c' ? As mentioned before the scheme 'c' does not exist in the documentation.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

print(urlparse('C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/impala/thrift/ExecStats.thrift').scheme)
```

By the way I am using Anaconda3.

Comment: `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/impala/thrift/ExecStats.thrift` is not a URL.

Comment: @user2357112 this seems to be bug in the impyla library as it uses urlparse to find the thrift file. Since Windows file paths are different thus it does not work.

Comment: I don't see anything in impyla that tries to parse a non-URL as a URL. I do see several places where you might mistakenly pass it a filesystem path instead of a URL, though. If you're doing that, that's your bug, not impyla's.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry I meant it as a bug in ThriftPy. Please check line 487 in thriftpy\parser\parser.py

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug. It looks like ThriftPy is dead and the developers recommend ThriftPy2 now, and ThriftPy2 supports the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). I don't know if I'd use either of these projects, though.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah but the Impyla project uses the buggy release. So what do I do ?

Comment: Uh, no, it looks like they're using ThriftPy2. You should be able to use file URIs, as in `file:///...`

Comment: @user2357112 thats weird but it seems when I installed from PyCharm this is the error I am getting. What am i doing wrong ? I didn't obviously intentionally uses an older release.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks. I had to update my release to 0.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage in, garbage out.

You've told `urlparse` to parse something that is not a URL. `urlparse` did its best. In this case, the `C:` looks like a URL scheme specifier, like the "http:" in `http://blah.blah.blah/...`, so `urlparse` decides the scheme is `c`.

Comment: This is a bug in the impyla library as it uses urlparse to find the thrift file.

Comment: Sorry I meant ThriftPy Library.